# NodeJS sub-projects installation

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a large project that contains multiple sub-modules, many of which are optional. And I have each sub-module sitting in its own folder with local `package.json`.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create an integral `package.json` that would be able to run `npm install` on a specific subset of those modules.

**Question**

Is there a more civilized approach these days than just running `npm install` from every sub-module folder? I want to be able to halt the integral installation when it fails for one module, and hopefully do it on a declarative level within `package.json`, rather than implementing such logic myself. Plus, I want `postinstall`-s run on each package (if present), and then one of the integration package.

Other than that, maybe there is a better way today to manage such projects? I'm open to any suggestions!

Comment: I haven't used it much myself so I'll refrain from calling it an answer - but I believe [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) does things like it sounds you want.

Comment: @Aurast I have read through its docs and examples, and it does look like a solid solution. In case you want to make it an answer ;) And it helped me find [some alternatives](https://blog.bitsrc.io/3-lerna-alternatives-for-building-a-js-component-library-3906628e8d02).

Comment: Nah I don't know enough about it to make a good answer, but glad it helps!